# Why doesn't my regex match text with $ character in it?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, pcre

I'm using `preg_match_all()` to search for some custom markup in a user template.  However, the function isn't matching strings that contains a `$` character.

The template tags can take two forms: `[TagName]` and `[TagName|some text here|some other text here]`.

Here is the regex that I'm using:

```
preg_match_all('/\[([^\]\|]+)(\|)?([^\]\|]*)\|?([^\]\|]*)\]/',$thank_you_screen_text,$thank_you_tags,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

These strings all match:

```
[Name1]
[AddTour|Yes!|no]
[NumberOfPersonsForRoomOut| x 2889 =|          ]
[CardholderName|Cardholder's Name:|]
```

However, any string with a `$` character in it fails.  It will not match the string at all.  These do not match at all:

```
[NumberOfPersonsForRoomOut| x $2889 =|          ]
[NumberOfPersonsForRoomOut| x \$2889 =|          ]
[RoomSubtotalOut|\$|]
```

I've tried it out using the Regex Tester at [regex101.com and it works there](https://regex101.com/r/pKeVWB/1).  What am I doing wrong?

---

The above results are on a server using PHP 5.5.22 with PCRE Library Version 8.34 2013-12-15.

However, I tried it on a couple of other servers, and everything matches as I would expect! The other servers are PHP 5.5.38/PCRE 8.38 and PHP 5.5.15/PCRE 8.34.  It doesn't seem to be the version of PCRE that is the problem.  What else could be causing this behavior on a particular server?

Comment: `preg_match_all('/\[([^\]\|]+)(\|)?([^\]\|]*)\|?([^\]\|]*)\]/', '[RoomSubtotalOut|\$|]', $m, PREG_SET_ORDER); echo $m[0][3];` outputs `\$`. Hence, `$` is included into the array of matches. And it is unclear what you mean by "it fails".

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov On my server, the example you give outputs nothing.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov By "it fails", I mean that it does not match any of the string at all: `echo $m[0][0];` outputs nothing.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I tried this on a different server, and it worked.  Which version of PCRE are you using?

Comment: PHP versions 5.6 and 7.1. PCRE library version is 8.39. The code captures `$` on https://eval.in/ and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php, by the way.